# Salaries of Star Trek Guest Stars

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, behind-the-scenes, production

What was the salary range of the guest stars on the original *Star Trek* series?

Comment: This is currently an open-ended question (you list some "main" guest stars without defining what a "main" guest star is, and you say "etc." so this is not a complete list). Therefore it is not suitable for this site. Please narrow down the question.

Comment: This post has nothing to do with sci fi. It's about tv show extras salaries. Better suited for https://movies.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Villan I disagree with that; it is about the production of a well-known sci-fi series and should be on topic.

Comment: @Rick are you looking for a complete list, or just for a general indication? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Also, explaining _why_ you want to know might help as well.

Comment: tangentially related - in the chapter from "These Are the Voyages" re: Roger C. Carmel's appearance in season 1, there is a paragraph re: Jerry Finnerman's (production, camera, lights) contract that was established at the same time. He says he (Jerry) received $800/wk in season 1, $900/wk in season 2, and $1000/wk in season 3

Comment: if you could get your eyes on these, there might be some answers found: https://rockhurstauctions.com/LotDetail.aspx?inventoryid=4510

Comment: I bet William Campbell made a bundle. Just a guess, of course.